# How to clear extra Microsoft Reserved Partitions

Tags: windows-10, partitioning

I have an old Dell laptop that I used while teaching Comp Sci at a university.  That was about 10 years ago. I have done many things with it, including putting one (maybe more) Linux systems on it.  I have cleared the intruders and want to put a new one on there, but the drive is still cluttered.  There are multiple MS partitions near the end of the drive, which considerable space between them.  I have no idea how they originated.  I have no idea what they do.  I have no idea what would happen if I deleted one or more.  As things stand I can boot Windows 10, and I'd like to keep it so.  But I'd like to clean up the space a bit.

I currently have Fedora as the lone intruder, because I don't know how to remove it and
restore the original Windows boot system.

The current partitions according to lsblk (running from a live disk):

```
NAME       MAJ:MIN   SIZE TYPE FSTYPE   LABEL
sda          8:0   931.5G disk          
├─sda1       8:1     500M part vfat     ESP
├─sda2       8:2      40M part vfat     DIAGS
├─sda3       8:3     128M part          
├─sda4       8:4     750M part ntfs     WINRETOOLS
├─sda5       8:5   482.4G part ntfs     OS
├─sda6       8:6     964M part ntfs     
├─sda7       8:7     8.4G part ntfs     PBR Image
├─sda8       8:8       1G part ext4     
└─sda9       8:9    59.6G part btrfs    fedora_localhost-live
```

The current partitions according to gdisk (running from a live disk):

```
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.8

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.

Command (? for help): p
Disk /dev/sda: 1953525168 sectors, 931.5 GiB
Model: ST1000LM024 HN-M
Sector size (logical/physical): 512/4096 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): EF31CBDE-1D6D-4E94-A26A-018DB7BBBFAF
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 1953525134
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 792238013 sectors (377.8 GiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048         1026047   500.0 MiB   EF00  EFI System Partition
   2         1026048         1107967   40.0 MiB    FFFF  Basic data partition
   3         1107968         1370111   128.0 MiB   0C01  Microsoft reserved ...
   4         1370112         2906111   750.0 MiB   2700  Basic data partition
   5         2906112      1014648831   482.4 GiB   0700  Basic data partition
   6      1874585600      1876559871   964.0 MiB   2700  
   7      1935951872      1953523119   8.4 GiB     2700  Microsoft recovery ...
   8      1014648832      1016745983   1024.0 MiB  8300  
   9      1016745984      1141743615   59.6 GiB    8300
```

Partitions 8 and 9 are /boot and / of Fedora; I'll delete them when the rest is accomplished.
The problems are partitions 6 and 7 which are floating in the midst of empty space.  It is not clear that they are important.  It is not clear that they can be relocated.  But I would like to consolidate the free space.

How can I consolidate safely?

Comment: 7 is dell recovery partition for the original OS, safe to delete if you no longer care about recovering the original OS. 8 may be the boot partition for windows.

Comment: Actually, 8 is Fedora's /boot.  The remaining question is 6.  I don't recognize it and it's NTFS, so it's not Linux.

Comment: sorry i meant 6

Comment: So if 6 is the Windows Boot partition, can it be moved (or even dropped)?  Expecially since I'll be booting with GRUB for the forseeable future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some partitions are addressed by number and some by their partition type,
and unallocated space is not counted (no number).

This means that partitions can always be moved.
As long as you keep their order, the computer should continue to work
just the same. Where partition-type is used to locate the partition,
the position in the disk is not important (for example the EFI
partition).

You may therefore move up partitions 6 and 7 so as not to leave any
unallocated space, congregating all the unallocated space at the
end of the disk.

Deleting partitions 8 and 9 will not cause a problem, as they are
located at the end of the disk, so this will not cause partition numbers
to change. You should take care to remove the Linux boot from the EFI.

Partition editing is dangerous, as any error can cause the lose of the disk.
You should take an image backup of the disk and prepare the boot media
or any other mechanism to be able to restore the disk to a non-booting
computer.

I remark that the nature of most of your partitions can be derived from
their code, as listed in
[Partition type GUIDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table#Partition_type_GUIDs),
as follows:

```
ef00 EFI System 
0700 Microsoft basic data 
0c01 Microsoft reserved
2700 Windows RE 
8300 Linux
```

Comment: Perhaps partitions can be moved by some tools, but Windows refused to remove or delete partitions 6 and 7.  This raised the concern that there might be a reason.There is also a hidden conflict between your comments that "partitions can always be moved" and "editing is dangerous".  Perhaps some data is "immovable" as parts of NTFS partitions sometimes are, because other parts refer to them by absolute address.  This would make moving them very dangerous.  So I did some experiments -- see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I investigated by making copies of the GPT partition table and partitions 6 and 7, using Linux tools dd(1) and gpart(8).  Now being pretty sure that I could repair any damage, I deleted both partitions.  Windows continued to boot normally.  Since the partitions data was presumably still there, I worried that something might refer to them with absolute addresses; so I created a partition that covered all the space that included those (now deleted) partitions, and zeroed the whole thing (with dd if=/dev/zero.....).  Windows continued to boot normally.  So harrymc was right.  I'm accepting that answer.

My answer: I could delete both partitions (though it took Linux tools to do it), and reuse the space.

WARNING: I still don't know if this would work if I were not using the GRUB boot loader.  It is likely, but unproven.